# Android Ads XML Attribute was missing

Tags: android, ads

When I run my app I get error `XML attribute adSize was missing` on my banner. My XML code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemes.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitID="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```

My onCreate code:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("AD_ID");

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), ANDROID_ID)).build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemes.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

schem**a**s, not schem**e**s